# Did Murder She Wrote plan for a handsome young man in each episode?

Tags: analysis, production, casting, murder-she-wrote

I started re-watching *Murder, She Wrote*. When I started the second season, I realized that I was seeing a handsome young man in almost every episode. Sometimes it’s a bit character like a deputy, security guard or ranch hand, sometimes they are a minor character.

Was this a known strategy the producers used to appeal to the audience demographic of older women?

A couple of examples and some bigger stars…

- [Charles Taylor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0653447/characters/nm0852107?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t10)
- [Stephen Shortridge](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0795160/?ref_=tt_cl_t6)
- George Clooney
- Tom Selleck
- Billy Zane

Comment: https://www.pentadact.com/2014-08-08-the-formula-for-an-episode-of-murder-she-wrote/ ...  in all seriousness, at least in the first 9 or so seasons the episodes were _VERY_ formulaic

Comment: Yep...it’s still a strategy. The acting world can be cruel.

Comment: It was in Angela Lansbury's contract. ;)